# jquery ul toggle problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
        <ul id="reportType">
            <li>A</li>
                <ul id="Ul1">
                    <li>B</li>
                    <li>C</li>
                </ul>
            <li>AA</li>
                <ul id="bpmReportsList">
                    <li>D</li>
                    <li>E</li>
                </ul>
            <li>AAA</li>
        </ul>

<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#reportType').children('li').click(function() {
        $(this).find('li').toggle();
 });
});
</script>
```

When you click one of the upper li's (the A, AA, AAA) i want it to toggle the li beneath it but it doesn't do that

I know it chooses the right li because i managed to hide the specific li but not whats under it

any thoughts?

thanks

doron

Comment: The `li` 'children' aren't children of the parent `li`. Your indenting is a little misleading. The A is at an equal level as the Ul1.

Comment: Yep, the UL needs to be inside the LI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indenting makes it seem like you think the `ul`s are children of the `li`. However, this is not the case because the `ul`s aren't wrapped inside the parent `li` at all.

You might want something along the lines of this instead: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/KNFhu/1/.

```
<ul id="reportType">
    <li>A
        <ul id="Ul1">
            <li>B</li>
            <li>C</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>AA
        <ul id="bpmReportsList">
            <li>D</li>
            <li>E</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>AAA</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Your jQuery code is fine, you only needed to make a small change to your HTML.**

The only change is to make your `ul` elements children of your top level `li` elements, as shown below:

```
<ul id="reportType">
    //Item 1
    <li>A
        <ul id="Ul1">
            <li>B</li>
            <li>C</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    //Item 2
    <li>AA
        <ul id="bpmReportsList">
            <li>D</li>
            <li>E</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    //Item 3
    <li>AAA
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Updated jQuery to handle Nested Lists:**

```
$('#reportType li > ul').each(function(i) {

    var parent = $(this).parent('li');

     var ul = $(this).remove();
     parent.click(function(){
            ul.toggle();
     });

    parent.append(ul);
});

// Initially hides all sub-lists
$('ul ul').hide();
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rionmonster/jd5aW/) | [**Working Demo (with Nesting)**](http://jsfiddle.net/rionmonster/jd5aW/1/)

Comment: Updated to handle nested lists :) Thanks AlienWebguy

Answer (score 0):

Your `<ul>`'s should be nested inside the `<li>`'s, like so:

```
     <ul id="reportType">
        <li>A
            <ul id="Ul1">
                <li>B</li>
                <li>C</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>AA
            <ul id="bpmReportsList">
                <li>D</li>
                <li>E</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>AAA</li>
    </ul>

<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#reportType').children('li').click(function() {
    $(this).find('li').toggle();
   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ul` elements needed to be wrapped in the `li`'s, not put underneath them:

```
<ul id="reportType">
    <li>A
        <ul id="Ul1" class="hidden">
            <li>B</li>
            <li>C</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>AA
        <ul id="bpmReportsList" class="hidden">
            <li>D</li>
            <li>E</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>AAA</li>
</ul>



$('#reportType').children('li').click(function() {
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
});
```

Working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GB5Dv/1/)